# Unable to login to Android app using hashed password

Tags: java, php, android, password-encryption

I have been following a tutorial in order to create a login for an Android based application, however after encrypting the passwords I am unable to get authenticate users. I have been searching for a solution to the problem for a few days now and still no luck. I am hoping that it is something simple that I have missed.

[Tutorial playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxffHgiJ64M&list=PLe60o7ed8E-TztoF2K3y4VdDgT6APZ0ka)

There are also loads of people in the comments that have had the same issue as me on Video 6 (Last video in the playlist).

[GitHub Repository for tutorial](https://github.com/tonikami/NEWLoginRegister)

Any support would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advanced!

Register.php

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

function registerUser() {
    global $connect, $name, $username, $email, $password;
    $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $name, $username, $email, $passwordHash);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     
}
function usernameAvailable() {
    global $connect, $username;
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?"); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    $count = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 
    if ($count < 1){
        return true; 
    }else {
        return false; 
    }
}
$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  
    if (usernameAvailable()){
    registerUser();
    $response["success"] = true;  
}
print_r(json_encode($response));
```

?>

Login.php

```
<?php
require("password.php");
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $passwordHash);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $UserID, $Name, $Username, $Email, $PasswordHash);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = false;  

 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
    $response["success"] = true;  
    $response["name"] = $name;
    $response["email"] = $email;
    $response["username"] = $username;
    $response["password"] = $password;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

?>

LoginRequest.java

```
package com.###########;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {
private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://....................../login.php";
private Map < String, String > params;

public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener < String > listener) {
super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
params = new HashMap < > ();
params.put("username", username);
params.put("password", password);
}

@Override
public Map < String, String > getParams() {
return params;
}
```

}

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.###########;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
final TextView registerLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRegisterHere);

registerLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(registerIntent);
}
});

bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
try {
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

if (success){
String name = jsonResponse.getString("name");
String email = jsonResponse.getString("email");

Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", name);
intent.putExtra("username", username);
intent.putExtra("email", email);

LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
else {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
.setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
.create()
.show();
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
};

LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
loginRequest.setShouldCache(false); // Disables Caching for Volley so that multiple login requests can be submitted.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
queue.add(loginRequest);
}
});

}
}
```

Comment: Each time you hash the password it creates a unique hash, so when you login and hash, you'll never get a match. You should instead use `password_verify()` as prescribed.

Answer (score 1):

In login.php you should change this:

```
//$passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); remove
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
```

Each time you hash the password it creates a unique hash (due to a randonly generated salt each time the function is run), so when you login and hash, you'll never get a match. You should instead use [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Once you retrieve the password from the query, you can then verify:

```
password_verify($password, $response['password']);
```

Comment: Hello Jay, Thank you so much for your response!
Where would I place 
password_verify($password, $response['password']);
In my login.php file? 
I have tried to add it in a few places but when I run the app as long as the user is registered in the database any password logs them in.
Please could you advise where I am still going wrong?

Comment: Hello Jay, I still can't work out how to use password_verify. Please can you advise me on what I need to do in order to implement it? Thank you once again, your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read [this](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).